# Uploading a file automatically for speed test?

Tags: php, javascript, uploading

I am building a Web UI for a device for internet connection and one of the requirements in it is a speed test.
I know the basic concept of how speed test works. A file is downloaded for a limited time then the same file is uploaded again and the speed is tracked at regular intervals.

Downloading the file is not an issue, but how am I supposed to upload the file without the client knowing that the file is getting uploaded?  I've read through a lot of documentation, but I'm still not able to get the answer to how I will upload the file from clients machine without asking him to select the file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a file, you could have JavaScript generate random data and send it to the server using AJAX.   Since the data would be generated from a random number generator, there would be no need to have the user choose a file.

Comment: yap have tried that ...and its working.just not being able to track the upload speed though

Comment: How are you planning to track the speed of a file upload?

Comment: @Abhi If you know the amount of data you have sent and how long it took to send it you know the upload speed.

Comment: I was successful in getting the download and upload speed. But i am facing another problem now. The amount of data stream that i am sending seems to be good enough for IE8 but in IE9 this seems to overload the buffer due to which i am unable to calculate the download speed